# Объяснение не нужно. Можно ли раздельно писать?

Tags: частица-не, прилагательными, предлоги

```
У Розенталя:
```

Примечание 2. Различается написание с не безлично-предикативных слов на -о и созвучных с ними кратких прилагательных и наречий. Ср.:

```
– Дать воды? – Не нужно. 

– Объяснение ненужно.
```

Но ведь краткие прилагательные могут писаться с НЕ отдельно, так как

тот же Розенталь пишет:

Примечание. В зависимости от смысла не с краткими прилагательными, как и с полными, пишется то слитно, то раздельно; ср.: наша семья небогата (примерно то же, что бедна) – наша семья не богата (т.е. среднего достатка); эта девушка некрасива (утверждается отрицательный признак) – эта девушка не красива (отрицается положительный признак), адрес неизвестен (утверждается «неизвестность») – адрес не известен (отрицается «известность»). Ср. также: Невелика беда. – Не велика, казалось бы, эта дистанция для стайеров.

Согласно этому примечанию, можно написать:

Объяснение не нужно.

А Примечание 2. можно понять так, что НЕ пишется раздельно, если *нужно* - это безлично-предикативное слово, и слитно, если *нужно* - краткое прилагательное.

Comment: Я что-то не могу придумать фразы с кратким прилагательным "нужно"...  Торможу, видать.

Answer (score 6):

Возможны оба варианта: Объяснение не нужно, не надо ничего говорить. Объяснение ненужно (напрасно), оно ничего не изменит.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) НЕ с предикативным наречием всегда пишется **раздельно**:

**Не нужно** беспокоиться обо мне ― я устроился во всех отношениях прекрасно (Максим Горький). "Мне **не нужно** клятвы, ― сказала Лиза, ― довольно одного твоего обещания" (А. С. Пушкин).

2) НЕ с кратким прилагательным может писаться **слитно или раздельно**: не нужен (бесполезен) или не нужен (не является необходимым). Кроме того, влияют **различные факторы**: усилительные слова для отрицания или утверждения, вопросительная частица ЛИ, наличие однородных прилагательных с одинаковой формой написания.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Помилуйте, да эти черкесы известный воровской народ: что плохо лежит, не могут не стянуть; другое и **ненужно**, а всё украдёт (М. Ю. Лермонтов). Замечательно устроено в жизни то, что все сложное **ненужно** и все нужное несложно (митрополит Антоний).

Все это мне **совершенно ненужно**, думал я. Всем, что было **ненужно и неинтересно** Вадиму, занимался Альберт.

Такое рождение **не нужно** для так называемого общественного идеала.

А вот это-то **совсем и не нужно**! И **вовсе не нужно** бросать их, если только в них нет ничего противного нравственному закону.  Вот раз приехал Казбич и спрашивает, **не нужно ли** баранов и мёда; я велел ему привести на другой день (М. Ю. Лермонтов).

Answer (score 4):

> Объяснение не нужно. **Можно ли** раздельно писать?

Скорее, раздельное написание ***не/нужно*** даже **предпочтительнее** слитного.

РОС (2012) фиксирует **только раздельное** написание ***не*** с краткими формами от ***нужный***:

> ***не нужен, не нужна, не нужно, не нужны***